# How to change color of the plot when it is called in evalin function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am new to matlab gui desgining. I am trying to plot the variables from the workspace. I have to plot three different variables together on the same plot with different colors. My code looks likes this : try

```
evalin('base',['plot(',a,',',x,')'])
grid on
hold on
evalin('base',['plot(',a,',',y,')'])
hold on
evalin('base',['plot(',a,',',z,')'])
```

catch ex
    errordlg(...
      ex.getReport('basic'),'Error generating linear plot','modal')
end

How can i make changes in evalin command so as to make plots of different color for each variable set. Please help

Comment: I have never used evalin, but have you tried C=[1 0 0]; evalin('base',['plot(',a,',',z,',',Color,'C')'])

Comment: yes, it says undefined function or variable Color

Comment: If it says that probably I have made some mistake in the code I posted. Dont copy it, but set the Color property to C.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to replace the `hold on` command with `hold all`, which will cause later plot commands to cycle through the default set of plotting colours.

(Note: you only need one `hold on`/`hold all` here)

If you need to choose specific colours for your plots, you can specify line formatting just as you would in a normal `plot` command.  Just remember that to make a single quote within a string you must escape it by using two (`''`).

```
plot(1:10,1:10,'r');
```

becomes

```
evalin('base','plot(1:10,1:10,''r'')')
```

Comment: thanks, it finally worked this way   evalin('base',['plot(',a,',',x,',''r'')'])
    hold all
    evalin('base',['plot(',a,',',y,',''b'')'])
    hold all
    evalin('base',['plot(',a,',',z,',''k'')'])
    grid on